# Matlab repetitive plotting for a number of variables

Tags: matlab, stata

I'm plotting a number of variables, say `x,y,z` in Matlab (there are plenty of them in the real code...). Just to avoid any stupid mistakes, is there anything like in Stata where you can define a list of local variables and using loop to plot for each variable of the list? For example

```
 local varlist "x y z"
 local n: word count `varlist' 
 local i=1 
 while `i'<=`n' {
     local var: word `i' of `varlist'
     hist `var'
     local i=`i'+1
 }
```

Plotting in Stata seems implausible, as the data has multi-dimensions.
Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: The Stata code can be greatly simplified to ``foreach v of varlist x y z { hist `v' }``. (Adjust to multiple lines, as comments don't allow block code).

Comment: `foreach v in x y z ` will work too.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured out how-to. The data type in Matlab that serves as varlist shall be cell arrays. The Matlab translation of the above Stata code is

```
varlist={x,y,z}
for i=1:length(varlist) 
  figure(i)
  temp=cell2mat(varlist(i)) %Transform cell array to matrix (vector)
  hist(temp) 
end
```

Comment: The other passivity is to make a function with either (a) `x`, `y` or, `z` explicitly or (b) a `varargin`.